# apply a function to all element on collection of collections

Tags: java

Suppose that we have a collection of collections, we want to apply a function to all elements how do you do that?
I know the answer wrong, but it was correct:

```
for (Collection<T> col : collection)
 if (col != null)
 for (T item : col)
 doSomething(item);
```

Comment: Besides your question: I strongly recommend to use { } for any loop, if, whatever. You see - so often one thinks: "Hey, it is just one statement, i dont need the stupid {}" .... and then 5 months later, you add a second statement, and you dont pay attention, and wooosh, something is wrong.

Comment: @EddyG: That's a good idea for empty loops. It's just stupid verbosity otherwise. Just use proper formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it exactly like you're doing it in your example.

(Maybe even check `item` for `null` if it can be `null` and if `doSomething` expects its argument to be non-`null`.)

Comment: you cannot use enhanced for loop for that. can you?

Comment: @KickButtowski Yes you can, why couldn't you?

Comment: i think if you wanna do any changes to your collection if you need to use iterator not enhanced for loop or may be I got the question wrong?

Comment: Only if you want to modify the collection.

Comment: it's not clear what dosomething does, so you should flag this as unclear